# Query gives desired results but would like apply window function in case expression using this logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Looking for a better solution, this query I wrote works for me, I would like to know if there is any better approach or same logic which I could used in the case expression.

I have written a query which give the max count for each id for respective quarter using window function and then pulling seqnum which is 1 and giving the results.

I would like to know **is it possible to use the same query in case expression with similar logic**.

```
select id,Quarter_yr, country
from (select id,Quarter_yr, country, count(*) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by id, Quarter_yr order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from  table 
      group by id,Quarter_yr,country
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: fty its a `case` *expression* not a statement. Its not clear what you are trying to achieve? What do you mean when you say use same query in case expression? Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @Dale K will add example and results to for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this query is what you're looking for

```
select top(1) id, Quarter_yr, country, count(*) as cnt
from table 
group by id, Quarter_yr, country
order by count(*) desc;
```